# mt_rand() in php doesn't generate new number on every refresh but in every 5

Tags: php

Is there some kind of caching issue?

I've sql statement which updates column in mysql.

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET user_sessions = user_sessions +1, user_password_token = ". mt_rand(1000000000,9999999999) ." WHERE user_name = '". $mysqli->real_escape_string($user_name) ."' AND user_password = '". $mysqli->real_escape_string($user_password) ."'");
```

In db I see token gets update only few times in every 5 refresh. And mostly it gets same values! Bits the idea of random doesn't it?

Number that gets repeated is mystic: 4294967295.

So is php caching this function?

I also noticed if I output mt_rand with echo this problem disappears.

:S

p.s. wait, is my browser not refreshing page? But this would not explain repeated number anyways.

Comment: Learn about the limits of 32-bit integers

Comment: @MarkBaker explain it to me or link relevant docs.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php - (`The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.`)

Comment: @MarkBaker This has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: @MarkBaker You where actually very right :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about this, but maybe you could add a random/date hash to each call. As I read in [fireflake](http://tech.fireflake.com/2009/06/16/how-to-avoid-a-page-being-cached/)

> Being dissillusioned by the current state of cache control (not the header, the subject) I ended up doing what probably most people are doing allready. Appending a random 10 character string to every call I ever make effectivly fooling the browser that this information might be improtant and making it update the page properly. Just append it to the back of every GET and include a random field in every POST.

Give it a try to see if it's a caching problem!

Answer (score 0):

I ran `mt_rand(1000000000,9999999999)` snippet alone and didn't get same values. To understand whether it is about MySQL caching or PHP caching, Run your function out of query function and assign a variable. Then put the variable in query function. If the result same, it is probably about MySQL.

Otherwise, a function to try:

```
    function nonce($size=32){//256 bit == 32byte. 
    $ret="";
    for($x=0;$x<$size;$x++){
        $ret.=chr(mt_rand(0,255));
    }
    return base64_encode($ret);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I did as you said. make random number variable and echoed it. Also put it inside sql statement. I found that sometimes these numbers mismatch! When they mismatch 4294967295 is what gets saved to column...

Comment: Hi. I put a function. Can you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I got it... and the magic number 4294967295 has everything to do with the problem.

Simply generating < 10 digit number should do it. Mark Baker was totally right.